# PowerShell Having trouble with Foreach to copy data

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I'm having trouble with my foreach. The point is to copy the data of another user than the main user in a computer to a NAS, if there is one.
Here's the script:

```
    $name2 = "Autres Utilisateurs"
    $env:USERS = "C:\Users\"enter code here
    $env:NAS = "\\ltrec\recup\"
    
    
    foreach ($other in $admin){
        if ($other -notlike $env:USERNAME)
        {
            New-Item -Path "$env:NAS\$name" -ItemType Directory -Name $name2
            Robocopy.exe ($other.FullName) "$env:NAS\$name\$name2" /E /Z /R:3 /W:5 /TBD /NP /V /XJ /XA:SH /XD "$env:users\Public" "$other\Appdata"
        }
    }
```

At this point of the PowerShell script, the mainuser data already have been copied to the NAS inside of a folder
When the foreach finds another user, he does copy the datas into a new folder in the NAS, but he also copies the datas of the main user AGAIN.
Can you help a PowerShell noobie to understand why ?

Comment: You're trying to loop through the contents of a variable `$admin` - but nowhere else is that variable assigned to. Where does `$admin` come from, and what are you expecting it to contain?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that ```$admin = Get-ChildItem $env:USERS```
I'm trying to get the script to determine "If I find another user than the main user, than I'll copy his files too in a folder in the NAS."

Comment: So you probably want `if($other.Name -ne $env:USERNAME)`?

Comment: Why is that ? I thought -ne was about a value about file weight.

Comment: `-ne` is the "**n**ot **e**quals" operator

Comment: @RedSpade, I've never seen the Environmental Variable of $Users.  Is the idea to get the current username (which is `$env:Username`) and then check for any other user folders in C:\Users?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked !
Sorry if it sounded so simple, I'm just starting haha.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Exactly, the point is to get all the users other than the main user (Except hidden ones like default and public) and copy those users data as well.

Comment: OK, check my answer down below.  It's bascially just a code review and cleanup but it will work.  One thing you might want to do is check to be sure you don't have too many admin or service accounts in a typical C:\user directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem here.  Most of the changes are just picking more obvious variable names to make it easier to change.

Also, I would caution against setting variables at the `$Env:` scope as these won't be available unless you set them, and can lead to confusing errors if used too frequently.

The changes here are breaking the NAS destination into more semantically obvious values, and then adding those together to make easy to work with code.
For instance, instead of $admin, let's change that variable name to be `$currentUser`.  Same thing with the `$NasDestination` and other vars.

```
$currentUser = $env:UserName
$allUsers = Get-ChildItem C:\users 

$baseNasPath = "\\ltrec\recup"
$nasDestination = "Autres Utilisateurs"
$fullNasPath = "$baseNasPath\$nasDestination"

foreach ($userDirectory in $allusers){
   $thisUserName = $userDirectory .Name
   if ($thisUserName  -ne $currentUser)
        {
            New-Item -Path "$fullNasPath\$thisUserName " -ItemType Directory -Name $name2
            Robocopy.exe ($userDirectory.FullName) "$fullNasPath\$thisUserName " /E /Z /R:3 /W:5 /TBD /NP /V /XJ /XA:SH /XD "$userDirectory\Public" "$userDirectory\Appdata"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, it's helping me improve
I had another problem yesterday with `$Env:Nas` on the `New-Item -Path "$env:NAS\$name" -ItemType Directory -Name $name2`
PowerShell returned an error saying that the username and password were wrong, and that the path was wrong too, replacing it with the real path instead of the variable fixed it.
I'll be more careful with my variables.